# Add navigation property to Membership schema

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-membership

I have an Entity Data Model for my Web Site that includes a table with some extra data for the registered users (called UserInfo). Currently, I'm setting the id of the new rows of UserInfo using the `Membership.GetUser(...).ProviderKey`.

What I want to do is to add a navigation property to my UserInfo table to point to the corresponding Membership row for that user but, due I have not the Membership schema in my Entity Designer, I can't figure out how to stablish this link between the tables.

Any idea?

Thanks very much,

Comment: My advice is not to add navigation props to the membership provider.  You would need to be careful not to add any dependencies or the default stored procedures in the Membership provider will fail on actions like DeleteUser.  If it were me, I'd use the built in Profile provider to store the user info instead of the UserInfo table you've added. That's what it's there for:)

Comment: I guess I did not explained well. I don't want to add the navigation property to the membership schema, but to my own schema. I want to add a nav. prop. in my schema pointing to the Membership schema. I also have take the Profile provider into account, but I think its structure is not optimal to store too much information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've finally decided it's easier simply to add a property to my UserInfo table (called guid) that store the guid of the MembershipUser schema.